# Meshlab: mesh semplification with fixed patch size

Tags: meshlab

All,
I'm using meshlab to simplify the overall mesh of a given .STL model.
Usually I make use of the embedded QECD algorithm. Nonetheless I'm not able to reduce the mesh imposing an upper-bound limit for faces dimension, that shouldn't exceed a specific area limit.
Some help?

Answer (score 1):

This could be a reasonable option to be added in the future.
Two possible solutions worth being explored in the meantime:

1. simplify as usual, then just refine the faces larger than a given threshold using *midpoint subdivision* and finally reproject the vertex geometry onto the original mesh.  Given the fact that usually large faces appear only on very flat areas, reprojection will works correctly...
2. try to use the Isotropic Explicit Remeshing filter with a low value for  *Max surface distance* as an alternative to QED